# Loading view from another storyboard into view of another storyboard

Tags: ios5, storyboard

I have a requirement like this.

The app is implemented like a slide panel UI which we find in facebook or path app.
I am using JSSlidePanel (https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels) and it requires 3 controllers to be added,

```
slidePanellcontroller.leftPanel = leftsideViewController;
slidePanellcontroller.centerPanel = centerViewController;
slidePanellcontroller.rightPanel = rightsideViewController;
```

I created a separate storyboards for slidePanellcontroller and for centerViewController. slidePanellcontroller is loaded from main storyboard, and centerViewController will be loaded from another storyboard called tabbar storyboard. Basically centerViewController is a tab bar controller.

Now I am not sure how to add the centerViewController's view into the slidePanellcontroller view.

Please provide any inputs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Firsts instantiate the other storyboard:

```
UIStoryboard otherStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"otherstoryboardfilename" bundle:nil];
```

Then instantiate the view controller by the identifier you set for it in Interface Builder.

```
UIViewController *centerViewController =
  [otherStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"centerViewControllerIdentifier"]
```